# Is "git rev-parse --short" aware of the current directory?

Tags: git

Some `git rev-parse` commands are sensitive to which directory the command was run from.  (This is why `--prefix` exists)

Is `git rev-parse --short HEAD` one of those commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (per edited question): since `HEAD` always specifies the current revision and is not dependent on a path within the work-tree, `--prefix` has no effect here.

[Original answer (which includes the above) below.]

---

It's not really clear to me what you intend to ask here.

Internally, `git rev-parse` does locate the current work tree and other items.  If run with no additional arguments, though, it does nothing useful.  For instance:

```
$ git rev-parse --short
fatal: Needed a single revision
```

This particular `git rev-parse` command simply fails.  It will do so regardless of any `--prefix` or lack thereof.

(If there's no Git repository it fails even earlier:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

but this is not very interesting.)

The `--short` option simply shortens the hash ID presented on success.

The hash ID produced by parsing a revision specifier *can* depend on the work-tree, but does not always.  For instance:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

produces the current (or `HEAD` or `@`) commit hash.  Using `--prefix` will not affect it.  But:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:./path
```

produces the tree or blob hash for the given `path` argument relative to the current position within the repository; here, using `--prefix` *will* affect it.

Meanwhile, `git rev-parse` can be used to do things other than produce commit hashes.  Here both `--short` and `--prefix` can become entirely irrelevant.  For instance:

```
$ git rev-parse --sq-quote --short --prefix x HEAD:./Documentation
 '--short' '--prefix' 'x' 'HEAD:./Documentation'
```

so it really matters what other parameters and options you are supplying.

Comment: Yes, I meant `git rev-parse --short HEAD` instead of `git rev-parse --short`.  I have updated the question.